# How to mock service?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-http

I have login function inside my LoginComponent:

```
login() {
        this.loading = true;

        this.subscription = this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.em.changeNav(1);
                this.loading = false;
                this.Auth.setToken(result);
                this.router.navigate(['/code']);
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
            },
            err => {
                this.error = JSON.parse(err._body).error;
                this.loading = false;
            });


    }
```

`this.authenticationService.login` is the service which send http request to api...

Here is the test:

```
it('should login', fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'login');

        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
        button.click();

        //CHECK IF LOGIN FUNCTION CALLED
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })

    }));
```

How can I mock `this.authenticationService.login` service and assert things in subscribe method?

**EDIT**

Test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers, HttpModule, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';
import {
    MockBackend,
    MockConnection
} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {EmitterService} from '../emitter.service';
import {AuthTokenService} from '../auth-token.service';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
    let backend: MockBackend;
    let service: LoginService;

    let component: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        class LoginServiceStub {
            login() { }
        };

        class RouterStub {
            navigate(url: string) { return url; }
        }


        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LoginComponent],
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                LoginService,
                EmitterService,
                AuthTokenService,
                { provide: LoginService, useClass: LoginServiceStub },
                //                { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('Should log in and navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(inject([LoginService, Router], (authService: LoginService, router: Router) => {
        spyOn(component, 'login');
        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');

        spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
        button.click();
        tick();

        expect(component.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
    })));

});
```

Problem with this is `login` function from component is never called When I console.log inside `login` method in component it display message...

This is Html part:

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<img class="loading-img" *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />

              <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
             <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Your email" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Email is required</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
                 <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Your password"  class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="login" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>


            <div *ngIf="error" style="margin-top: 20px;" class="text-center alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center login-down" >
                <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register now</a>
                <a routerLink="/forgot" routerLinkActive="active">Forgot password</a>

            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create mock class for service:

```typescript
class AuthenticationServiceStub {
    login() {}
};
```

then provide it in `configureTestingModule`:

```typescript
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: AuthenticationServiceStub },
    { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
  ]
})
```

inject in your test

```typescript
inject([AuthenticationService, Router], 
   (authService: AuthenticationService, router: Router) =>
```

wrap it in **async**(+`whenStable`) or **fakeAsync**(+`tick`) or use **jasmine.done** directly for waiting execution of async methods

```typescript
it('Should log...', fakeAsync(inject([AuthenticationService, Router]
```

and mock `login` method like:

```typescript
spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true) );
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xuqKuQQlR30ubB2UypF0?p=preview)**

Here is the entire spec:

```typescript
describe('Welcome component tests', () => {
    let comp: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        class AuthenticationServiceStub {
            login() {}
        };

        class RouterStub {
            navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
        }

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: AuthenticationServiceStub },
                { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents()
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.login'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('Should log in and navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(inject([AuthenticationService, Router], (authService: AuthenticationService, router: Router) => {
        const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
        spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true) );

        el.click();
        tick();
        const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

        expect(navArgs).toBe('/dashboard');
    })));
});
```

Comment: I have problem make it work... I get this error: `inline template:38:16 caused by: router.routerState is undefined
`

Comment: ` I found that this part couse it: `{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }`

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker? I mock router.navigateByUrl

Comment: But you use navigate method

Comment: It is probably problem with angular version I am using `2.1.0` I tried to exclude routing and add just `true` variable inside succes request but test  still not working...

Comment: It is very hard for me to create plunker of this... I am `(ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" ` can it be a problem?

Comment: Can you share stack trace?

Comment: Try to put `debugger;` inside of `login` method and observe it in console

Comment: Sorry. i see `Problem with this is login function from component is never called `

Comment: Try to remove `form` and keep only `<button (click)="login()">`

Comment: I found what couse problem with `login function` this part: `spyOn(component, 'login');` when I remove it from test it show log from login function but show new error: `Some of your tests did a full page reload! `

Comment: Hi, I have followed your Question and answer, after applying I have encountered a problem, please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971117/error-expected-spy-getgoogle-to-have-been-called

Comment: @yurzui Please help, on the above comment's link.