# Test angular for observable

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, observable, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test only the function `calculateExchangeCurrency`

```
@Input() referenceText;
@Input() exchangeText = 55; // ONLY TO CHECK IF TEST COMMANDS READ CORRECTLY
// More data...
public calculateExchangeCurrency() {

  let referenceNumber = parseFloat(this.referenceText.replace(/,/g,''))
  return Observable
    .interval(this.timeToOtherRequest)
    .startWith(0)
    .flatMap(() => this.exchangeService.getExchange('USD', 'EUR'))
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('here');
        this.exchangeText = response.rates['EUR'] * referenceNumber;
        console.log(this.exchangeText);
    });

}
```

This function only needs the parameter `referenceText` and Its purpose is to calculate the variable `exchangeText`, this variable is inserted in html via ngModel:

```
<input type = "text" class = "form-control result-exchange" [ngModel]="exchangeText | number" placeholder = "EUR" disabled>
```

**TEST**

- The function consumes a service and I know that I need to create a fake response for this service `exchangeService`, for that with `spyOn` I created a fake response
- I'm going to test if the variable `exchangeText` calculated in the function is on the html, for that motive I read from `result-exchange` class

code:

```
// Fake data for service
let testExchange = {
  rates: {
    EUR: 0.851256
  }
};

describe('HomeComponent', () => {

  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let exchangeService: ExchangeService;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, TextMaskModule, HttpModule],
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
      providers: [ ExchangeService ]
    })

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    exchangeService = TestBed.get(ExchangeService);

  });

  it('should calculate number', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    //  Unique input that needs the function
    component.referenceText = '456.5';

    // Create fake response of service
    let spy = spyOn(exchangeService, 'getExchange').and.returnValue(of(testExchange));
    component.calculateExchangeCurrency();

    // Wait the page is loaded
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();

      // Get result from html
      el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.result-exchange'));

      // Test
      expect(el.nativeElement.value).toBe('396.259');
    })

  });

});
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Problems:

- In console I realize the test enter to the function but no replace the service for the fake response, It consumes from my real service because 0.851256*456.5 = 388.598 != 371.259
- Expected '55' to be '396.259'. It means the input with class `exchangeText` never is updated. Because it needs to be 371.259 in theory, but if the fake service works well then It needs to be 388.598

I'm learning test in angular, sorry if I made mistakes.
Will be ok If also there are suggestions.

Comment: You should create mockExchangeService and use it in providers section of 
 TestBed.configureTestingModule    as value for ExchangeService.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41201866/6528560